# Changing Clock Format Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, clock

I would like to change the clock formatting from "Sep 11 5:01 PM" to display "Sunday, 11 September 2022, 5:01 PM".

The current format is:

```
[Mo] [dd] [(h)h]:[mm] [X]M
```

and I wish for it to be formatted as:

```
[Day], [dd] [Month] [yyyy], [hh]:[mm]:[ss] [X]M
```

How would I go about that?

Comment: I also found: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3465/panel-date-format/ maybe this can help.

Comment: Check the suggested duplicate. In your case, `%A, %d %B %Y, %I:%M:%S %p` should be added in the *Format* text box.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 does not display the date anymore, despite setting it via CLI and dconf editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `gnome-tweaks` via `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` command, and set it there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, Tweaks only allows one to toggle on/off weekday and seconds and not the year, it doesn't allow for changing the order of the items, nor whether or not the full words are displayed.